# How to run batch files in background while running multiple files in parallel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing, io-redirection

I am writing a batch file which will execute 4 other batch files in parallel:

```
@echo off

echo %time%

(
    start call s1.bat
    start call s2.bat
    start call s3.bat
    start call s4.bat
) | set /P "="

echo %time%
```

But this is opening 4 new windows.
Can anyone help, how to avoid opening multiple windows and run all those 4 batch files in background?

Adding `/B` is on of the option, but I don't to where to add it exactly.

```
(
    start /B call s1.bat
    start /B call s2.bat
    start /B call s3.bat
    start /B call s4.bat
) | set /P "="
```

Is giving me an error:

> ```
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> ```

As I do not want to use VB or any other script, how to do it in batch?

Comment: You can't hide a batch files window without using VBscript or some other third party utility. The best you are going to get is to use the `START` commands minimize option.

Comment: Also, you'd `start cmd.exe` with the arguments `/D /C` `Call` and your batch file. _`Call` like `Start` are both internal to `cmd.exe`._

Comment: how to use /B of start ? it says ,  Start application without creating a new window.

Comment: I did not get your second point. so I should use only start <batchfile> ?

Comment: Create some test batch files which do something simple, perhaps `@Echo %TIME% > "%~n0.log"`, and try it. However, you will not be able to run a batch file without the cmd.exe window showing even for a fraction of a second, the best you could hope for is to use the `/Min` option of `Start`, _(which you've already been told)_, and even then you'd see it 'flash'. If you want to run it hidden, you'll need to use Windows Scripting Host, (or other similar utility), or run it as SYSTEM, from Window Task Scheduler.

Comment: when I try to execute all 4 batch files like below , it executes well.


`START /B CMD /C CALL s1.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s2.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s3.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s4.bat
`

but, when I try to execute all batch simultaneously , I get an error "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe."

`
(
START /B CMD /C CALL s1.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s2.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s3.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL s6.bat
) | set /P "="
`

I am not able to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess the batch files `s?.bat` execute quite quickly, right? what happens when you temporarily insert the command `timeout /T 2` into each of the batch files? does the pipe error still occur? does the master script (the one containing `( … ) | set /P "="`) await completion of the other four batch files?

Comment: also remove the part with the pipe. `| set /P "="`

Comment: Thank you for the response. One of the ```s?.bat``` file contains ```tcpdump``` command , which never returns prompt. So its hanging and I have to terminate it by sending ```CTRL+C``` . till that point ```| set /P "="``` waits. I have added ```timeout``` in batch files too.  I want to run all 4 batch files at a same time. Hence using ```| set /P "=" . Is there other way by which I can call all batch files at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting problem! It seems that there is some conflict with the redirection handles.

The main script awaits execution of the sub-scripts with the following code (on Windows 10):

```
(
    > nul start "" /B cmd /D /C call s1.bat
    > nul start "" /B cmd /D /C call s2.bat
    > nul start "" /B cmd /D /C call s3.bat
    > nul start "" /B cmd /D /C call s4.bat
) | set /P =""
```

The `> nul` redirection prevents any data to be written to the pipe `|`. It seems as soon as there becomes anything written to the standard output handle *STDOUT* (`1`), the main script does no longer wait (and sometimes the error message `The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.` arises, possibly depending on how fast the sub-script(s) execute(s)). However, as soon as the `/B` is removed, output to *STDOUT* by the sub-scripts does not affect the behaviour of the main script, which waits for all sub-scripts, and `> nul` is therefore no longer necessary.

The explicit `cmd /C` part is necessary because `start` would otherwise implicitly use `cmd /K` when starting internal commands like `call` which leave non-terminated processes `cmd.exe` behind upon completion of the respective sub-script.
The `/D` switch just prevents any auto-run commands to become executed.

---

When you use normal `start` without `/B` for running the sub-scripts, a new instance of the command interpreter is started, that is the process `cmd.exe`, and a new instance of the console window is started as a process `conhost.exe`.

Now using `start /B` still creates a new process `cmd.exe` but it uses the *current* process `conhost.exe`.

I do not know what exactly happens in the background and how all these processes interact, but it appears to me that the issue is connected to the lack of `conhost.exe` processes when using `start /B`. Maybe `conhost.exe` is establishing the redirection handles and hence the pipe. Anyway, as long as there is nothing written to the pipe, there is nothing to conflict, so `set /P =""` waits for the related handle to become closed.